# Find 4 specific corner pixels and use them with warp perspective

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm playing around with OpenCV and I want to know how you would build a simple version of a perspective transform program. I have a image of a parallelogram and each corner of it consists of a pixel with a specific color, which is nowhere else in the image. I want to iterate through all pixels and find these 4 pixels. Then I want to use them as corner points in a new image in order to warp the perspective of the original image. In the end I should have a zoomed on square.

```
Point2f src[4]; //Is this the right datatype to use here?
int lineNumber=0;
//iterating through the pixels
for(int y = 0; y < image.rows; y++)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < image.cols; x++)
    {
        Vec3b colour = image.at<Vec3b>(Point(x, y));
    if(color.val[1]==245 && color.val[2]==111 && color.val[0]==10) { 
        src[lineNumber]=this pixel // something like Point2f(x,y) I guess
        lineNumber++;
    }
    }
}
/* I also need to get the dst points for getPerspectiveTransform 
and afterwards warpPerspective, how do I get those? Take the other 
points, check the biggest distance somehow and use it as the maxlength to calculate 
the rest? */
```

How should you use OpenCV in order to solve the problem? (I just guess I'm not doing it the "normal and clever way") Also how do I do the next step, which would be using more than one pixel as a "marker" and calculate the average point in the middle of multiple points. Is there something more efficient than running through each pixel?

Something like this basically:

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's not the _clever_ (nor _correct_) way to look for a specific color. But you'll learn that with some experience. Please answer to: 1) which OpenCV version are you using? 2) You have 2 images with 4 markers (one colored pixel, circle, whatever), and you want to warp one image to the other?

Comment: OpenCV 2.4.9. I have one image and this image has 4 colored pixels/ markers. I want each of these pixels to be the corner of a new quadratic image (so that if the base image had a parallelogram on it and each of the corners were a marker the outcome would be a quadratic image zoomed to the new square). I can try to illustrate it though, wait a moment.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/zcZBFfG.png This should illustrate what I meant. Changed my mind in one way though, I guess 4 different colors would be better to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from an image with colored circles as markers, like:

[image]

Note that is a png image, i.e. with a loss-less compression which preserves the actual color. If you use a lossy compression like jpeg the colors will change a little, and you cannot segment them with an exact match, as done here.

You need to find the center of each marker.

1. Segment the (known) color, using [inRange](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?#cv.InRange)
2. Find all connected components with the given color, with [findContours](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?s#findcontours)
3. Find the largest blob, here done with [max_element](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max_element/) with a lambda function, and [distance](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/distance/?kw=distance). You can use a for loop for this.
4. Find the center of mass of the largest blob, here done with [moments](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?s#moments). You can use a loop also here, eventually.
5. Add the center to your *source* vertices.

Your *destination* vertices are just the four corners of the destination image.

You can then use [getPerspectiveTransform](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?#getperspectivetransform) and [warpPerspective](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?#warpperspective) to find and apply the warping.

The resulting image is:

[image]

Code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    // Load image
    Mat3b img = imread("path_to_image");

    // Create a black output image
    Mat3b out(300,300,Vec3b(0,0,0));

    // The color of your markers, in order
    vector<Scalar> colors{ Scalar(0, 0, 255), Scalar(0, 255, 0), Scalar(255, 0, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 255) }; // red, green, blue, yellow

    vector<Point2f> src_vertices(colors.size());
    vector<Point2f> dst_vertices = { Point2f(0, 0), Point2f(0, out.rows - 1), Point2f(out.cols - 1, out.rows - 1), Point2f(out.cols - 1, 0) };

    for (int idx_color = 0; idx_color < colors.size(); ++idx_color)
    {
        // Detect color
        Mat1b mask;
        inRange(img, colors[idx_color], colors[idx_color], mask);

        // Find connected components
        vector<vector<Point>> contours;
        findContours(mask, contours, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

        // Find largest
        int idx_largest = distance(contours.begin(), max_element(contours.begin(), contours.end(), [](const vector<Point>& lhs, const vector<Point>& rhs) {
            return lhs.size() < rhs.size();
        }));

        // Find centroid of largest component
        Moments m = moments(contours[idx_largest]);
        Point2f center(m.m10 / m.m00, m.m01 / m.m00);

        // Found marker center, add to source vertices
        src_vertices[idx_color] = center;
    }

    // Find transformation
    Mat M = getPerspectiveTransform(src_vertices, dst_vertices);

    // Apply transformation
    warpPerspective(img, out, M, out.size());

    imshow("Image", img);
    imshow("Warped", out);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```